# \indent and \par not providing indentation within proof environment

Tags: lists, indentation

I have a proof nested within an enumerate. I have set \parindent and \listparindent but still do not paragraphs indented inside proof environments. Code below

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm, amssymb, sgame, bbm, enumitem, verbatim}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\setlength{\parindent}{0.5 in}
\setlength{\listparindent}{0.5in}

\begin{document}


\begin{enumerate}

\item This is a question on hw

\begin{proof}
    This is my answer. First paragraph. Words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words\par

    Second paragraph should be indented.  words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words
\end{proof}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default behaviour; a list environment like `enumerate` clears the value of `\parindent`. The following minimal example demonstrates that:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}
\setlength{\listparindent}{0.5in}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]% 0.5in paragraph indent

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \lipsum[1-2]% No paragraph indent
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

If you wish to restore `\parindent` inside a list, you'll have to update it within the list, like in the following example:

[image]
    \documentclass{article}

```
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{enumerate}
  \setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}
  \item \lipsum[1-2]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The same holds for restoring `\parindent` within `proof` as part of an `enumerate`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}
  \item \lipsum[1-2]

  \begin{proof}
    \lipsum*[3]

    \lipsum*[4]
  \end{proof}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

If you want a `\parindent` to be active with all of your `enumerate` environments, you easily set this globally using [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem):

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{listparindent=0.5in}
```