# Decrease horizontal space in enumitem lists

Tags: spacing, lists, enumitem, amsthm

To subdivide longer proofs of theorems, I use two list environments defined using `enumitem`: `pfsteps` for numbered steps and `pfparts` for labeled parts.

**Horizontal space problems**

1) In the `pfsteps` enumerate list, there seems to be a bit too much horizontal space *after* the colon that follows the step number — more space than would follow a colon in ordinary text.
 2) In both the `pfsteps` enumerate list and the `pfparts` description list, there is definitely too much horizontal space between "Proof" and the first label of the list.

**Questions**

Problem 1) can be fixed by using something like the commented-out line `\hspace{-1pt}` after the colon in the definition of `label` for `pfsteps`. But is there a nicer way to decrease this space?

How can Problem 2) be fixed, for both the `pfsteps` and the `pfparts` list environments.

**Sample source**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{amsthm}

% Indent ``Proof.''
\usepackage{xpatch}
\newlength{\normalparindent}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\normalparindent}{\parindent}}
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\hskip\labelsep}{\hskip\labelsep\hskip\normalparindent}{}{}

\let\oldproofname=\proofname
\renewcommand{\proofname}{\sffamily\bfseries{\oldproofname}}


\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{pfsteps}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[pfsteps,1]{%
  %label=\sffamily{Step {\arabic*}:\hspace{-1pt}},
  label=\sffamily{Step {\arabic*}:},
  ref=\normalfont{\arabic**},
  wide,itemsep=0pt,topsep=0pt
}

\newlist{pfparts}{description}{1}
\setlist[pfparts,1]{%
  font=\normalfont\textsf,
  itemindent=0pt,
  wide,
  itemsep=0pt,topsep=2pt,
}

\begin{document}

Proof using \verb!pfsteps! enumerate list.

\begin{proof}

\begin{pfsteps}

\item do this first. The way to begin is to start at the very beginning and use the definitions involved to get going.

\item do this next. After the initial step, we proceed by showing something interesting next.

\item conclude with this. That's it! \qedhere

\end{pfsteps}

\end{proof}

\bigskip

Proof using \verb!pfparts! description list.

\begin{proof}

\begin{pfparts}

\item[Sufficiency.] First we show that the stated condition is sufficient for the conclusion to hold.

\item[Necessity.] To conclude the proof we show that the stated condition is a necessary condition for the conclusion. \qedhere

\end{pfparts}

\end{proof}

\bigskip

For comparison, a proof that is not divided into steps or parts.

\begin{proof}

Here is the proof of the main result.
%
\end{proof}


\end{document}
```

**Output**

In the output shown below, the red arrows point to excessive space. (And for comparison, the green arrow points to the normal space after a "Proof."

[image: Excessive horizontal space in lists]

Comment: In my opinion you should use an empty line after the the begin of the `proof` environment. The indented `Step` leaves an disrupted look of the text

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: You're probably right about that style, but how achieve the empty line? Is there a more graceful way than inserting, say,  `\mbox{}` after `\begin{proof}`?

Comment: this has been dealt with before.  i'm looking for possibilities.  is this any help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/319717/579 ?   or this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/348472/579 ?

Comment: this one really should be considered a dupe: [How to change the (horizontal) distance between “Proof” and the first enumeration symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/319949).  it has been closed as a dupe to a question that asks about theorems, but proof goes by the same rules.

Comment: Method at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17449/annoying-space-before-the-first-item-in-an-enumeration-which-starts-a-theorem to use `leftmargin=*` with my defined `enumitem` environments unfortunately destroys the normal indentation of my labels, due I think to the necessary (I think) inclusion of the `wide` setting. The extra space preceding the label that needs to be removed should only affect the label of the *first* item in the list.

Comment: Answer by Gonzalo Medina at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17449/annoying-space-before-the-first-item-in-an-enumeration-which-starts-a-theorem works for the lists beginning immediately after "Proof": start with `\begin{pfsteps}[leftmargin=*]`, end the environment after the 1st item, restart it with `\begin{pfsteps}[resume]`. But this is certainly a verbose and awkward thing to have to do while coding a proof! What still seems to be lacking is a way, when creating the list macro, to treat the 1st item differently.

Comment: If, following the style opinion of @Christian Hupfer, I instead leave an empty line before the first list item inside the proof, I don't see how to create a new kind of proof environment that uses the `\leavemode` trick suggested in `amsthmdoc`.

Answer (score 2):

The space before the label item (Step) is controlled with `labelindent` and the space between label and text is controlled with `labelsep` -- choose some values appropiate for you, my given values are just guesses.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{amsthm}

% Indent ``Proof.''
\usepackage{xpatch}
\newlength{\normalparindent}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\normalparindent}{\parindent}}
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\hskip\labelsep}{\hskip\labelsep\hskip\normalparindent}{}{}

\let\oldproofname=\proofname
\renewcommand{\proofname}{\sffamily\bfseries{\oldproofname}}


\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{pfsteps}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[pfsteps,1]{%
  %label=\sffamily{Step {\arabic*}:\hspace{-1pt}},
  label=\sffamily{Step {\arabic*}:},
  ref=\normalfont{\arabic**},
  wide,itemsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,
  labelindent=0pt,
  labelsep=0.5ex,
}

\newlist{pfparts}{description}{1}
\setlist[pfparts,1]{%
  font=\normalfont\textsf,
  itemindent=0pt,
  wide,
  itemsep=0pt,topsep=2pt,
  labelindent=0pt,
  labelsep=0.5ex,
}

\begin{document}

Proof using \verb!pfsteps! enumerate list.

\begin{proof}

\begin{pfsteps}

\item do this first. The way to begin is to start at the very beginning and use the definitions involved to get going.

\item do this next. After the initial step, we proceed by showing something interesting next.

\item conclude with this. That's it! \qedhere

\end{pfsteps}

\end{proof}

\bigskip

Proof using \verb!pfparts! description list.

\begin{proof}

\begin{pfparts}

\item[Sufficiency.] First we show that the stated condition is sufficient for the conclusion to hold.

\item[Necessity.] To conclude the proof we show that the stated condition is a necessary condition for the conclusion. \qedhere

\end{pfparts}

\end{proof}

\bigskip

For comparison, a proof that is not divided into steps or parts.

\begin{proof}

Here is the proof of the main result.
%
\end{proof}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Including `labelsep` is good, thanks. But including `labelindent` does *not* work: with it, every label except the first in the list is now flush left; all labels after the first should be given normal indents -- as my output shows (and in case the list does not begin immediately after "Proof", then the first label should be given a normal indent, too!).